# Failed to append image along with text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, signalr

This is my code I want to append image along with my text

Code:

```
 $(".ChatSend").click(function () {
            strChatText = $('.ChatText', $(this).parent()).val();
            var recievertext=  $('.ausername').html();
            if (strChatText != '') {
                var strGroupName = $(this).parent().attr('groupname');
                if (typeof strGroupName !== 'undefined' && strGroupName !== false)
                    chat.server.send($("#hdnUserName").val() + ' : ' + strChatText, $(this).parent().attr('groupname'));
//this code is not working
                    **var userphoto="<img  height=\"18px\" width=\"18px\" src=\"userimages/5.jpg\" />";
                $('.ChatText', $(this).parent()).find('ul').append(userphoto + strChatText);**
//end of this code is not working
                $('.ChatText', $(this).parent()).val('');
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the content in an `li` since you're appending to a `ul`

```
$('.ChatText', $(this).parent()).find('ul').append('<li>'+userphoto + strChatText+'</li>');
```